# How do you run multiple DelayedJob workers on a single Heroku dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, foreman, procfile

I am having trouble getting my dynos to run multiple delayed job worker processes.

My Procfile looks like this:

```
worker: bundle exec script/delayed_job -n 3 start
```

and my `delayed_job` script is the default provided by the gem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

When I try to run this either locally or on a Heroku dyno it exits silently and I can't tell what is going on.

```
foreman start
16:09:09 worker.1 | started with pid 75417
16:09:15 worker.1 | exited with code 0
16:09:15 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Any help with either how to debug the issue or suggestions about other ways to go about running multiple workers on a single dyno it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use foreman to start multiple processes on the same dyno.

First, add foreman to your Gemfile.

Then add a `worker` line to your **Procfile**:

```
worker: bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.workers
```

Create a new file called **Procfile.workers** which contains:

```
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
dj_worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

That will start 3 delayed_job workers on your worker dyno.

Answer (score 8):

Try changing your Procfile to:

`worker: bundle exec script/delayed_job -n 3 run`

Using `start` will create two daemons in the background and then immediately exit. Heroku thinks that your process crashed.

Using `run` keeps the workers in the foreground.

UPDATE: I use [Delayed Job Worker Pool](https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job_worker_pool) for this now.

Comment: Yes, been looking all over for this. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry to say this doesn't appear to work anymore.  Run will now ignore the -n arguments and always run a single process.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can't do this with delayed_job. A dyno is a process and a single delayed_job worker works on a single process.

There are other solutions to this though. If you can switch over to using Sidekiq then you can run quite a few workers on a single process since Sidekiq workers use threading. The trade-off here is that your workers will need to be thread safe.

Check it out: http://sidekiq.org/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the accepted solution of @infused, but ran into an issue with the worker processes crashing on startup with
`Bundler::GemNotFound: Unable to find a spec satisfying web-console in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is corrupted?`

The reason for that is that `foreman start` is looking for a `.env` file by default and read it: [Forman Manual](https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/).
Because the `.env` file was setup for a development environment, foreman was looking for the `web-console` gem and missing it.
Conslusion: If you see your worker not starting, check if you have a `.env` file that is unsuited for production and rename it or specify another file on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I used the ruint buildpack to run a Procfile.worker in a single (worker) dyno: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-runit